# How should I call a javascript class method from html?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I have a javascript class as follows:

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
}

Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
};
```

now I want to call method getinfo from my html file on an event. say I have a div like below:

```
<div ... onmouseover="getinfo()"></div>
```

now I know that above is not the proper method to call getinfo. So what is the best method to do it?

One way could be as below that I define a class object in windowonload() call and use the object to call the method getinfo(). But what if I have lot of classes for a big project and lot of objects. Then I need to define each object in windowonload() call which does not seem right to me. There must be a way to create objects on the fly. Kindly guide me?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, you'd need to have an Apple object somewhere to call the method on

Comment: Is each div supposed to have an Apple object associated with it?

Answer (score 2):

Declare your *class*:

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
}

Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
};
```

Create an instance of it:

```
var apple = new Apple("pink lady");
```

Then play with it:

```
<div ... onmouseover="alert(apple.getInfo())"></div>
```

Comment: Ok. I know that I need to define the object to call the method. But what If i have lot of classes. Then for each class I need to define an object before hand and then only I can access it. Isn't there is a way to create objects dynamically on html?

Comment: You can, but I don't see why you would... <div ... onmouseover="alert((new Apple("pink lady")).getInfo())"></div>

Answer (score 1):

To call the method you need to create an instance of the object, for example:

```
new Apple('Granny Smith')
```

You can keep the reference to the object in a variable, and use the variable to call the method:

```
var green = new Apple('Granny Smith');
var info = green.getinfo();
```

Or you can create the object on the fly and call the method directly:

```
var info = new Apple('Granny Smith').getinfo();
```

Generally it would make sense to create a instance of the object when the page loads, and use that later on.

Comment: I get your point. Now my question is do I have to define objects before the page loads or there is a way by which I can create objects dynamically after the page is loaded?

Comment: You can create objects at any time... I think you are trying to accomplish something in a round-a-bout way... Maybe you would receive more help giving a broader definition of your problem and asking for different advice

Comment: @Ravi: You can create objects at any time, from the class code is parsed up to right when you need to use the object. Your example class is too abstract to say what would be normal use for it, but normally there is a logical time for when you should create an object.